# Encrypt my DB before putting it in the asset folder to use it with SQLCipher?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

My app works with an already provided DB. I generate this one manually with a sqlite script and I put it on the asset folder of my android studio project.

I want to encrypt it and working with it using SQLCipher. I already implemented it on my android app, but I need to encrypt my DB BEFORE putting it on the asset folder, in order to provide the users with an already encrypted DB I can use using SQLCipher.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an encrypted SQLCipher database using the SQLCipher command line shell:

```
./sqlcipher foo.db
sqlcipher> PRAGMA key = 'foo';
sqlcipher> CREATE TABLE t1(a,b);
sqlcipher> INSERT INTO t1(a,b) VALUES('one for the money', 'two for the show');
sqlcipher> .q
```

You can find documentation on creating the SQLCipher shell [here](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/introduction/).  Alternatively, if you already have the database, you can use the [`sqlcipher_export(...)`](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export) convenience function to export a plain text database to a SQLCipher encrypted file.  You can run the `sqlcipher_export` function either through the SQLCipher command line shell, or programmatically on your Android device using SQLCipher for Android.

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks for your answer. For the moment I'm using an already existing DB as a .db file. But on the next versions of my app, the DB will be re-generated using a SQL script I created myself. Is there a way to implement the encryption method directly in it?